# Not able to solve "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to create a to-do list app in flutter. I am facing an issue with a widget that helps me to edit an already created to-do widget with respect to the title or description.

**This is the pic of my todo list HomePage**

[image]

**This pic of my edit button**

[image]

**I am facing an issue after I press the save button in this widget**

[image]

**This is the error that I am getting**

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _EditTodoPageState.saveTodo
package:todolist/Edit_Todo_Page.dart:47
#1      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:989
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:198
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:608
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:296
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:230
#6      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:563
#7      PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94
#8      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139
    (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#25bd2
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(189.1, 309.1)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(67.7, 11.1)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**This is my edit todo widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todolist/todo.dart';
import './todos.dart';
import './todo_form_widget.dart';

class EditTodoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Todo todo;
  const EditTodoPage({Key? key, required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditTodoPage> createState() => _EditTodoPageState();
}

class _EditTodoPageState extends State<EditTodoPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String title;
  late String description;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    title = widget.todo.title;
    description = widget.todo.description;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Edit Todo"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Form(
            child: TodoFormWidget(
              title: title,
              description: description,
              onChangedTitle: (title) => setState(() => this.title = title),
              onChangedDescription: (description) =>
                  setState(() => this.description = description),
              onSavedTodo: saveTodo,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  saveTodo() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    } else {
      final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context, listen: false);
      provider.updateTodo(widget.todo, title, description);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error in the "**saveTodo()**" method. I am not able to solve this error.

**This is my Provider widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:todolist/todo.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TodosProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Todo> _todos = [
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
    Todo(
      createdTime: DateTime.now(),
      title: "Wake up at 6:00 AM in the morning!!!",
    ),
  ];
  List<Todo> get todos => _todos.where((todo) => todo.isDone == false).toList();
  List<Todo> get todosCompleted =>
      _todos.where((todo) => todo.isDone == true).toList();

  void addTodo([Todo? todo]) {
    _todos.add(todo!);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTodo(Todo todo) {
    _todos.remove(todo);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool toggleTodoStatus(Todo todo) {
    todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
    notifyListeners();
    return todo.isDone;
  }

  void updateTodo(Todo todo, String title, String description) {
    todo.title = title;
    todo.description = description;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you haven't used `_formKey` in `Form` widget thats why `_formKey` `currentState` is getting null. Try to use `_formKey` in the `Form` widget and check it is not equal to null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todolist/todo.dart';
import './todos.dart';
import './todo_form_widget.dart';

class EditTodoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Todo todo;
  const EditTodoPage({Key? key, required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditTodoPage> createState() => _EditTodoPageState();
}

class _EditTodoPageState extends State<EditTodoPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String title;
  late String description;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    title = widget.todo.title;
    description = widget.todo.description;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Edit Todo"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TodoFormWidget(
              title: title,
              description: description,
              onChangedTitle: (title) => setState(() => this.title = title),
              onChangedDescription: (description) =>
                  setState(() => this.description = description),
              onSavedTodo: saveTodo,
            ),
          ),
        ),
     );
  }

  saveTodo() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    } else {
      final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context, listen: false);
      provider.updateTodo(widget.todo, title, description);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
}
```